# Use of key and values in dict python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict as follows:

```
replace={'/':',',':':','}
```

Now when I execute the below code

```
for key in replace: 
 　　　　print(Value)
```

it gives the following output,

```
>>:
>>:
```

I am using Python 3.5.2 and I am also new to using dicts. I expected the output to be

```
>>,
>>,
```

What am  I doing wrong here ?
Please help.

Comment: your code wouldn't run at all since replace isn't defined.

Comment: Are you sure you're executing that code? There are about two undefined variables there..

Comment: Unless you have `Value` defined somewhere which we don't see, this will fail with a name error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for value in replacements.values():
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to get value for a given key in Python:

```
replacements={'/':',',':':','}
for key in replacements:
    print(replacements[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead:

```
for k in replacements:
    print(replacements[k])
```